# Writing a function for excel that includes dates

Tags: excel, function

I am trying to help a co worker with a data sheet that involves dates. For example we have the date received which might be 06/14/14 and the product expired 7/14/16 I need to do two things. One is if the date between the dates is greater than 30 days I get the date in the column if its less than 30 days I get a return of Expired. so far I have tried =IF(A1-B1<30, "Expired", SUM) and when it does work I just get numbers in a negative or an error. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

If cell A1 has your earlier date, and cell B1 has your later date, then your formula could be:

```
=IF((B1-A1)>30, "Expired", A1)
```

Here, if the difference is not greater than 30 then it returns the date in A1. That's how I interpreted your scenario, anyway. Remember to change the formula cell format to 'date'.